# Do skins give any perks in SWBF?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

Do the faction skins in Star Wars Battlefront give any advantages or disadvantages to the player? Such as increasing the hitboxes, making it much easier to get headshots on players with the Twi'lek or Sallustian skins. And for the Scout Trooper and Shadow Trooper, give better vision, for the scout, and turn invisible with the Shadow Trooper? I am not at a high enough level to purchase these skins yet, but was curious so I can spend credits wisely.

Comment: The black armor makes you freaking impossible to see, so there's that.

Comment: only on maps like endor, if you use it on hoth you're an idiot. but if the skin can do what the shadow troopers do in survival then its incredibly useful.

Comment: @DCShannon I hadn't thought about the black armor... now I know what my next purchase will be... ;)

Comment: @TimS. its only for level 50 though, what i really want is the weequay head!

Comment: Ah, that explains why I don't have it yet. Still trying to get the DL-44 or whatever Han's blaster is called. Been killed by that one more times than I can count.

Comment: @TimS. oh, you're like level 25, I'm 36, and have all the available weapons, star cards that don't require the season pass. (which I am getting soon.)

Comment: @TimS. and it's the DL-44, and it's not actually that good. stick to the T-21, it's really accurate and kills with 3 shots. also, the cycler rifle is really good for close quarters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38108/discussion-between-parzival-and-tim-s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely the camouflage factor would be the reason here -- the stormtrooper/snowtrooper outfits are damn near impossible to see on the ice worlds, but easy as anything to spot on Endor. The opposite is true for the Rebel outfits (somewhat, as they are not totally one color).  I personally bought a stormtrooper outfit that doesn't wear a helmet, hoping that the blaring white body suit was diminished by the fact that they saw my face, giving pause to firing at me (with little to no success of course). I do try to change my skin to match the environment for any advantage though.

Comment: What about the hitboxes for the rebels, I don't want it to be really easy to headshot me.

Comment: I didn't develop the game, but I'd be extremely surprised if the hitboxes were in any way attached to the skins. The hitbox is part of the game mechanics, but the skins are literally just painted onto the models during the game.

Comment: fair enough i guess.

Comment: DICE also made it very convenient to automatically switch skins per map since they clearly have different effects per map.